# which approach is better to return true or false?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

May be my question is not important but It pop up in my mind whenever I do work on my project,So I want to know that which one is better approach in terms of performance and I also want to know are there any other side effects.

**Code 1:**

```
if ($result === TRUE){
    // some statements 
    return TRUE;
}else{
    // some statements
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
if ($result === FALSE){
    // some statements
    return FALSE;
}

// some statements
return TRUE;
```

**Please note** that I have to process some code when condition is true or false that's why I putted comment stating that **"// some statements"**

Comment: In my opinion the second one is cleaner, because it reduces nesting.

Comment: I don't think it really makes a difference but I would go with the first one because it gives more readability to the code.

Comment: code 2: there  are any any side effects in some situations?

Comment: no difference, if result is true check and return, if result is false, check and return. dont know about the cost of **else {}**

Comment: in `function` context `Code 2:` would be more convenient

Comment: I think the #2 is faster, as the compiler doesn't check ELSE block. And as I remember from compiler & computer architecture , the second one was what compilers prefer to write in assembly as it needs less instruction sets. But I can't prove it :)

Comment: The difference is negligible. Chances are the statements within the blocks have a much bigger impact (can't tell without seeing them) on performance than the checks themselves. Personally, I prefer the bucket clause (#2) because it has less lesting and clearly shows the happy path.

Comment: @shawn_parker check out my method of writing the above logic in my answer below..

Answer (score 3):

The performance of both is the same.
Pick the one that's better to read, the first one can lead you to get a V Form like

```
if($result) {

} else {
  for() {
    if($result2) {
      //code
    }
  }
}
```

so i would prefer the second one, which is much easier to read for advanced programmers, but a little confusing to beginners

Answer (score 0):

return $result===TRUE?TRUE:FALSE;

Comment: the OP wants to do execute some statements inbetween (note the "some statements comments in the OPs code). Also, if `$result` is a boolean anyway, you can just as well `return $result` directly.

Comment: @AlexisPeters what's the point of doing `!!$result`? double negation is hard to read and `return $result` does the same in less time.

Answer (score 0):

I always follow this pattern:

```
// declare result as true by default
$result = true;

// some logic that will decide on the status of result

if (!$result) // this is same as $result === false
{
    return $result = false;
}

return $result;
```

*Advantages:*

Else block is skipped. Hence less code, but this does not work if you are in requirement of else block.