# redirection issue in www to non www with ssl/https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a SSL certificate for non www URL: `https://domain.com`

I know there are many similar question, but none of them seems to solve my problem. Here is what I am trying to do:

**Problem:**

```
1) http://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com **www to non www DONE**

2) http://domain.com -> https://domain.com **http to https DONE**

3) https://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com/ **NOT DONE**
      - Getting ERROR ON Above URL number (3): Your connection is not private
```

So far, my .htaccess file looks like so:

```
# www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# https://www to htttps://
```

**Please note that** above code of .htaccess is working fine for my first and second problem, Now I want to solve my third problem

Here are the solutions that I already tried:

- [.htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)
- [htaccess force https and redirect www to non-www, but no other subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467329/htaccess-force-https-and-redirect-www-to-non-www-but-no-other-subdomains)
- MANY MORE

Comment: have you enabled your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes It is enabled.. look in my question I posted htaccess file code its working

Comment: If your code is working then what is the issue?

Comment: look in my question what i want to do???

Comment: redirect domain.com to domain.com?

Comment: redirect https: //www.domain to https: //domain

Comment: brother in comment I can't write my issue that's why i am saying you to look in question

Comment: Check out my answer if it works for you.

Comment: This seems somwhat weird. The first rule should meet the third requirement, which is HTTPS-agnostic. So the first rule should meet the first and third requirements, whilst the second rule should meet the second requirement. Perhaps try swapping them around? Silly, I know... Alternative try [this](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-https) followed by [this](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-non-www).

Comment: Edit: I've now seen your recent question-update. The SSL certificate you are using does not work on the non-www version, seemingly.

Comment: my SSL certificate is issued on non www URL, so I am redirecting all www url to non www

Comment: so I want to redirect https:// www to non www

Comment: WHY DOWN VOTE MY QUESTION????? WHO DID THIS???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

To redirect www to non-www (while using SSL)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your_domain.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your_domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

The last 2 are meant for online stores using SSL or to prevent any SSL errors while using SSL on some pages.

Update1:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Update 2

RewriteEngine On
Make all http use https:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxx.yyy/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make only www https use the non-www https:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www[.].+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxx.yyy/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Update 3:**

Check out this issue over here:

[.htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)

Comment: not working.. check my question again I done some changes on It

Comment: brother I want to do three redirect to same domain

Comment: @shawn_parker trying to derive a solution giv me some time.

Comment: @shawn_parker check my Update 1

Comment: brother look i wan to do that,

Comment: if someone type in url https:// www.domain.com then user must be redirected to https:// domain.com

Comment: I putted blank space in URL just for visibility on screen.

Comment: I will have to try it on your server myself if that is possible by any chance.

Comment: brother server is not mine.. My client has its credentials and I just have a ftp connection..

Comment: ftp connection with restrictions.

Comment: brother some one down vote my question.. can u up vote it

Comment: @shawn_parker try update 2 once again it has to work.

Comment: brother its not working.. thanking soooo muchhh for your help

Comment: if i find right answer then i will send you.. and definitely i will accept your suggestions as final answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104369/discussion-between-fakhruddin-ujjainwala-and-shawn-parker).

Comment: sorry... I was not present to accept your chat invitation

Comment: @shawn_parker you will require SSL for both the domains www and non-www to get it working

Comment: @shawn_parker its basically a chrome issue you are facing.

Comment: I have a SSL for non www URL and I just want to redirect https:// www to non www, so for this I need another SSL certificate

Comment: Yes that's what my research tells me.

Comment: No you got me wrong. What I think is you require ssl for both www and non-www to get it working. I do not have any updates on answer.

Comment: I understand it completely what you are saying

Comment: so other people can understand on which basis we declared this answer

Comment: @shawn_parker I have updated my answer once again. Its ok if it does not work. Let me know once you find a solution, I shall update the answer with your solution and you can then up-vote it and mark it correct.

Comment: brother look my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147030/which-approach-is-better-to-return-true-or-false may be you can give your views on this, If you like my question up vote it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. If this doesn't work then check in your site conf file you have `AllowOverride All`. If it is `None` make it `All`

Sample **site.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/directory/>
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: NOT A CORRECT ANSWERE

Comment: @Haridarshan - Over and above the answer not being valid, the formatting was incorrect. Please format your posts properly in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

The rule above will redirect

- http://www.example.com/

to

- https://example.com/

And

- https://www.example.com/

to

- https://example.com/

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: @shawnparker I tested the code on my apache server before posting it, it is working fine there. Apache 2* and 2.4

Comment: I am testing your code on my server and its not working brother