# redirect www URL to non www with https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

How can I redirect all www requests to non-www with https?

For example all following 3 URL`s:
http://www.example.com/about-us
http://example.com/about-us
https://www.example.com/about-us

Should redirect to https://example.com/about-us

I have tried answers posted at 
[redirection issue in www to non www with ssl/https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593803/redirection-issue-in-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)
and 
[.htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)
 but they are not working. My current rule is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code "

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

So , the scenario above is to catch all `http` with or without `www` by this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` and then catch all `www` with this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.` and then force all into `https://` .

**Note:** clear your browser cache and test it and if it's Ok change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection.

**Update :**

go to these lines in your `.htaccess` :

```
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

make them without `#` like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then go directly to the code in the last of page :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://phoddalo.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

change it to this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://phoddalo.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Test it and make sure you clear your browser cache .

If it is ok , change `302` to `301` as i mentioned above .

Comment: I tried your code and now all non ssl pages are getting redirected to ssl home page ie:

'code' https://example.com/about-us redirects to https://example.com

Comment: so , that what you need or not ? i understand that you want to force all to none www with ssl, am i right?

Comment: yes but instead of opening specific page, homepage is opened everytime. for example instead of opening about-us, contact-us pages it redirects to home page

Comment: sorry not understand ,explain it to me more

Comment: Some of the links are hard coded in website and they have non-ssl url`s. Upon clicking them instead of opening their ssl version, homepage is opened every time. For example I have a link  http://example.com/about-us now if I click it then https://example.com/about-us should open but page gets redirected to https://example.com (homepage)

Comment: Is there might be any problem with virtual host file? My website is hosted at Godaddy shared hosting.

Comment: AFAK SSL is for domain so if you add new pages, under that domain, they should follow the general rules unless you have some exclusion somewhere

Comment: are you sure putting /$1 when you changed yourdoamin with code above ? this line RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302] should be RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302] if you dont put /$1 after yourdoamin every page will go to home

Comment: Yes I am putting /$1 after my domain. Links to ssl pages are opening fine but links to hardcoded non-ssl pages gets redirected to homepage. My website is a blog and there might be hundreds of pages with hardcoded non-ssl links so its not possible to change them manually.

Comment: My website is https://phoddalo.com and I have put this code in .htaccess file:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://phoddalo.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]`
try visiting any page with http, it will redirect to https homepage.

Comment: No problem with your website at all , it worked fine for me really as what you want

Comment: Please try opening these pages `http://phoddalo.com/mcq` and `https://phoddalo.com/mcq` both are same but first one redirects to homepage.

Comment: u r right , please paste your .htaccess file , all of it

Comment: My website is built using drupal CMS and your code is at the end of file. https://pastebin.com/8jeLJ0xi

Comment: I have made changes as you suggested but still I am facing same issue. My updated htaccess is at `https://pastebin.com/gaC0S7du` Is there something needs to be done from hosting provider (godaddy) end?

Comment: did you see this line  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later

Comment: Yes I did as per your updated answer but still not working

Comment: Your pastebin code is not working, but I got it working by removing following 4 lines from .htaccess `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico` `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` Will it cause any issue on my website?